# Using Variable Manipulations in Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to create a Makefile with target file name = folder name. 
Instead of hard coding it  I used the function

```
FILE=$(PWD##*/)
```

I also tried 
`FILE=$(echo PWD##*/)`  and `FILE=$(echo $(PWD##*/))`.
But I am getting an error: un-terminated variable reference.
I know it's difficult to do such variable manipulations in Makefile. Is there a work around?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify Andrew Gillis's answer below, makefiles are not shell scripts, and you can't use shell script syntax directly when assigning makefile variables.  The `##*/` syntax works with _shell_ variables, inside _shell scripts_.  It won't work with make variables, within makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Setting FILE like this should work:

```
FILE = $(notdir $(PWD))
```

An alternative is to call out to shell to do the same:

```
FILE = $(shell basename $${PWD})
```

Comment: It worked the first time but when I tried re running it : it says Circular reference , dependency dropped.

Comment: generally that means a target has a dependency, and that dependency has a dependency on the target

Comment: Put another way, that error has nothing to do with this issue and you haven't shown any part of your makefile that would help diagnose it.  You should try to figure it out yourself and if you can't, open a new question with more details of your makefile related to the lines referenced in the error message from make.

Comment: Also, the quoting above is wrong: you should be using `$${PWD}` not `\${PWD}`